# Mobile devices scrolling below site

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website is scrolling below the `html` tags when I scroll on mobile devices.
I tried some stuff that I found like hiding `overflows` and setting `position relative` on the `body` but nothing of it is working.

code:

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 725%; }

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    position: relative; }
```

If you are on google chrome you can also visit [www.winkelmand.nl](http://www.winkelmand.nl/) to try it out by putting your browser in some sort of mobile form with Chrome devtools.

Notice you can scroll off the page when scrolling down.

**Extra** 
I would also like to disable horizontal scrolling without losing the content on the side of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason adding `user-scalable=no` in my viewport did the job. I am still able to scroll but it wont let me scroll off page.

First:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >`

Now: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >`

I don't exactly know how this works but it does, still thanks for the answers tho, I didn't know about `overscroll-behavior-y: contain;` and I think it can become usefull.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean the default scolliny behavior option, that recently got added in Chrome 63.
[Here is an atricle](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior)

```
body {
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```

Comment: This is also happening while opening the site on apple safari. Also adding the code didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Removed Horizontal bar]
You can disable the horizontal bar using below :

```
html, body {
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

and yes as @Jiib stated `overscroll-behavior`

Comment: I added this code, and also the `overscroll-behavior-y: contain;` but it still seems to scroll off the page. Or is this not visible with chrome devtools?

Comment: You should hide other pages which are not required, you are just changing their position not hiding them, that's why they are always in the DOM which leads to horizontal scroll bar